# ByteTrack with Yolov5

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolov5

In the training step of ByteTrack, I want to use Yolov5 instead of YoloX, so I try to run

`python3 tools/train.py -f exps/example/mot/yolox_x_mot17_half.py -o -c pretrained/yolov5x6.pt -b 1 -d 1`

with yolov5x6 pretrained weights from yolov5 model zoo, and I got this error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`

How can I fix this?
[ByteTrack repo](https://github.com/ifzhang/ByteTrack)
[Yovo5 repo](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to load Yolov5 weight into a YoloX architecture. You cannot interchangeably use YoloX/Yolov5 resources. You would have to replace everything related to YoloX by its YoloV5 counterpart if you want to use the latter.